# Jordan decomposition of a 2 by 2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I want to find the Jordan decomposition of the matrix
$$ 
M= 
\begin{pmatrix}
p & -\frac{p^2}{4} \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
Wolfram Alpha gives me the decomposition $M = S \cdot J \cdot S^{-1}$, where
$$ 
S= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{p}{2} & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, 
\quad 
J= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{p}{2} & 1 \\
0 & \frac{p}{2}
\end{pmatrix}, 
\quad 
S^{-1}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & -\frac{p}{2}
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
I have checked that $S^{-1}$ is indeed the inverse of $S$. However, if we multiply the three matrices we get
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & p \\
\frac{p}{2} & -\frac{p}{2}
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Where is the problem? I suspect that $S$ is not correct. What would be the correct decomposition?

Comment: Maybe you did the matrix multiplication wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you made a mistake somewhere in the multiplication, $SJS^{-1}$ is actually equal to $\begin{pmatrix} p & -\frac{p^2}{4} \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Well, I also did the multiplication with Wolfram Alpha. Now I have multiplied by hand and you are right. Thanks !